How to set Telegram monthly users
I’m building a telegram mini app, I noticed this monthly feature in bots of telegram mini app, how can do the same for my bot:
The example is in the image attached telegram bot
Tried using botfather, but couldn’t find a setting for that. Also cant find any decent solution online even chatgpt or maybe I didn’t ask the right question or something

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
